# WP Cron not executing after timespan

Tags: hooks, wp-cron

I trying to utilize `wp_schedule_single_event` to schedule an asynchronous task. However, my event was never called after 60 seconds. Do I need to do anything with `ldp_new_topic_event` hook before using it here? My site is running on a shared host.

Here is how I coded my schedule:

```
<?php

if ( !class_exists( 'LDP_Notifications' ) ) :

final class LDP_Notifications {

   public static function new_topic_notification( $topic_id = 0, $forum_id = 0, $anonymous_data = false, $author_id = 0, $is_edit = false) {

       // Do some stuff.
       // Based on some conditions the following is called:
       error_log('++++ schedule an event. I see this printed.');

       add_action( 'ldp_new_topic_event', 'LDP_Notifications::send_push_notification', 10, 2 );
       wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 90, 'ldp_new_topic_event', array( $message, $deviceTokens ) );
   }

   public static function send_push_notification( $message, $deviceTokens )  
   {
        error_log('Expecting this after 60 seconds but I never got it.');
   }
}

endif;

?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you visit your site after 60 seconds had passed to allow cron to run?

Comment: I did go to my site after 60 seconds. However im not aware of settings i must config for scheduler to run. Where might i find the settings to allow the schedule?

Comment: There are no settings, just that your will site only run any pending crons when someone visits the site (or if you have scheduled an external service to visit wp-cron )

Comment: Ok. Yep i did revisit the site way after 60 seconds but the scheduled was never observed. Do i need to do anything special with my hook prior to this? Or does add_action took care of it already?

Comment: Do you see your event when you `_get_cron_array()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom hook is never triggered because you are not subscribing to it the right way!

**Context**

Although you are calling it in your class function, it is never executed beyond that point.

Place the `add_action` function somewhere else like in a `plugins_loaded` hook. Put it outside your class where it can be seen.

**Dependencies**

Where are the variables $message and $deviceTokens declared? if they are not, the `wp_schedule_single_event` will fail! So no event is scheduled in the first place!

Comment: Awesome, I got it to work by moving `add_action` to the `plugins_loaded` hook. It only works after the timer had expired and that I revisited the website. Isn't it suppose to fire automatically when the timer expires? Here's how Wordpress describes the schedule in two sentences: `Schedules a hook which will be executed once by the WordPress actions core at a time which you specify. The action will fire off when someone visits your WordPress site, if the schedule time has passed.`  The first sentence give me an impression that it should fire without user intervention.

Comment: Yes the first sentence gives that impression, but the second sentence takes it away. That's how threaded apps work. It's sad but it's true. Now if you feel my answer has worked for you, then mark it as so. This way others can identify the correct answer quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't like the second sentence at all :)